# Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get the output when I hit the calculate button. I know that it is something simple that I am missing but I have been racking my brain over this all day and can't seem to get it to work correctly.  This is my updated code and still doesn't work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">



 function calc(){
 var price = document.getElementById("price");
 var shipping=parseFloat(calc(price));
 var total= price+shipping;
 if (price<=25){
 return 1.5;
 }
 else{
 return price*10/100
 }

 window.alert("Your total price with shipping and handling is $" + price + ".");
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="total" action="">
 Enter your amount:
 <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
 <input type="button"
 value="calculate"
 onclick="calc(document.getElementById("price")">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There is no `document.totalprice` element. Look at your browser's error console.

Comment: It looks like you have alot of basic mistakes. The best thing for you to do is try a online javascript tutorial like codeacademy and learn the basic syntax

Answer (score 2):

Change `parsefloat` to `parseFloat` : JavaScript is case sensitive.

Similarly, you used `on click` instead of `onclick`. The browser can't guess your will, you have to be precise.

Also, you didn't give a name to your form (I suppose you wanted to call it `totalprice`. But the best would be to give an id to this input and get the value like this :

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price">

...

var price = document.getElementById('price');
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `parsefloat` should be `parseFloat`
2. `on click` should be `onclick`
3. `calc` returns a Number, you are trying to call its return value as a function
4. The first three lines of JavaScript are not inside a function. This means that

   - They are trying to access elements that do not exist (and never will, you have no `totalprice` element)
   - They are trying to access elements before the user has typed a value into them

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

1. It should be `onclick` not `on click` (no space)
2. `calc(price)` is not the name of the function, but just `calc` is. To call it, you just need to write `calc(document.totalprice.price.value)`
3. It’s `parseFloat` (upper case `F`)
4. The `window.alert` is outside of the function body, so you will only get a single alert at the beginning, but not when you press the button
5. Similarly, you probably want to put all the other stuff inside the function too, so it updates when you click the button.
6. `document.totalprice` does not exist, so `document.totalprice.price.value` will not work.

Also note that the CDATA-comments are not needed. They were used in XHTML (served as XML) to make the content a plain text for the XML parser (without having to care about special characters etc.). As you just have the simple (and recommended) HTML(5) doctype, you don’t need this anymore.